# Android studio clicking buttons crashes simon says

Tags: android-studio, button, onclicklistener

So I am making a simon says game and I am having trouble letting the user click the colours so that the game can see if what the user clicked is right or not.

Right now I have implemented the onclick method for my buttons. The goal is that when the user clicks a button a certain number of times, the game will check if the pattern that was shown is the same as the pattern that the user gave. The game shows the patterns fine. However, clicking the button after the game has shown the pattern causes the game to stop working. I tried running the debugger but when I do the activity won't load so I can't actually click the button. But when I just run the game the activity shows but then crashes when I click the button.

This is the on create:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

int[] pattern;
int[] guess;
Button[] colours;
public int count;
public TextView Final;
public int score;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button green =  findViewById(R.id.Green);

    Button blue =  findViewById(R.id.Blue);

    Button red =  findViewById(R.id.Red);

    Button purple =  findViewById(R.id.purple);

    TextView Final = findViewById(R.id.Score);
    colours = new Button[]{green, blue, red, purple};

    int score = 0;
    do {
        pattern = showPattern(colours, score);
        guess = getGuess(colours, score);
    }while(Arrays.equals(pattern,guess));
    Final.setText("Score is" + score);
}
```

This is the onclick methods:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.Green:
                guess[count] = 0;
                count++;
                if (count >= score + 1 && Arrays.equals(pattern,guess)) {
                    score++;
                    pattern = showPattern(colours,score);
                    count = 0;
                }
                else if (count>=score + 1) {
                    String result = "You're score is " + score;
                    Final.setText(result);

                }

            case R.id.Blue:

                guess[count] = 1;
                count++;
                if (count >= score + 1 && Arrays.equals(pattern,guess)) {
                    score++;
                    pattern = showPattern(colours,score);
                    count = 0;
                }

                else if (count>=score + 1) {
                    String result = "You're score is " + score;
                    Final.setText(result);

                }

            case R.id.Red:

                guess[count] =2;
                count++;
                if (count >= score + 1 && Arrays.equals(pattern,guess)) {
                    score++;
                    pattern = showPattern(colours,score);
                    count = 0;
                }

                else if (count>=score + 1) {
                    String result = "You're score is " + score;
                    Final.setText(result);

                }


            case R.id.purple:
                guess[count] = 3;
                count++;
                if (count >= score + 1 && Arrays.equals(pattern,guess)) {
                    score++;
                    pattern = showPattern(colours,score);
                    count = 0;
                }
                else if (count>=score + 1) {
                    String result = "You're score is " + score;
                    Final.setText(result);

                }

            default:
                break;

        }

}
```

This is the getGuess method which I think is causing my app problems.

```
public int[] getGuess(Button[]  colours, int score) {
    guess = new int[score+1];
    colours[0].setOnClickListener(this);
    colours[1].setOnClickListener(this);
    colours[2].setOnClickListener(this);
    colours[3].setOnClickListener(this);

    while(count<score+1){

    }

    return guess;
```

This is the showPattern method:

```
public int[] showPattern(final Button[] colours, int score) {
    int[] pattern = new int[score + 1];
    Random rand = new Random();

    for (int j=0;j<score + 1;j++) {
        pattern[j] = rand.nextInt(4);



        switch (pattern[j]) {
            case 0:
                new CountDownTimer(2000,2000) {
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        colours[0].setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.lightGreen));
                    }


                    public void onFinish() {
                        colours[0].setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.green));
                    }
                }.start();
                break;



            case 1:
                new CountDownTimer(2000,2000) {
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        colours[1].setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.lightBlue));
                    }
                    public void onFinish() {
                        colours[1].setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.blue));
                    }
                }.start();
                break;

            case 2:
                new CountDownTimer(2000,2000) {
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        colours[2].setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.lightRed));
                    }
                    public void onFinish() {
                        colours[2].setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.red));
                    }
                }.start();
                break;


            case 3:
                new CountDownTimer(2000,2000) {
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        colours[3].setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.lightPurple));
                    }
                    public void onFinish() {
                        colours[3].setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.purple));
                    }
                }.start();
                break;
        }
    }
    return pattern;
}
```

I am expecting that once the public variable count has equaled the exceeded variable score and that both the guess and the pattern arrays equals then i can show the pattern and wait for the user to guess again. However, once a button is clicked the game stops.

(UPDATE) So I think in addition to the getguess method the do while loop seems to be messing up my code as well. Also the last line on the logcat reads

```
Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
```

Comment: I don't see you initializing the guess array anywhere.

Comment: In android studio you can use logcat to catch alot of problems like this that occur. This <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ayIR5a51Ohg">video</a> would help if you are unfamilar with it. Can you provide more of the code so that I can read the entire thing?

Comment: @JRowan I have created a method to initiate it but it still doesn't work. Though I appreciate you noticing that.

Comment: You have to remove the while loop in your getGuess method, and the do{}while loop in your onCreate method isn't doing what you think just do pattern = ... And guess = ... Without the do while.

Comment: @JRowan I did that but it still crashes when I click a button.

Comment: Put a break; into each of your cases in onclick method